# How to calculate a price per hour on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to calculate a price per hour with Start Time, End Time, and Price Per Hour  on MySQL?

This is my request at this moment:

```
$query = "SELECT
        requests.id as request_id,
        requests.request_type as request_type,
        service_types.name as service_type,
        requests.status,
        requests.provider_status,
        requests.amount,
        requests.s_latitude as latitude,
        requests.s_longitude as longitude,
        requests.confirmed_provider as provider_id,
        requests.user_accepted,
        requests.provider_accepted,
        providers.id as provider_id,
        providers.first_name as provider_first_name,
        providers.last_name as provider_last_name,
        providers.picture as provider_picture,
        AVG(provider_ratings.rating) as rating,
        provider_services.price as price_per_hour,
        requests.start_time,
        TIMEDIFF(now(),requests.start_time) as time_elapsed_since_start,
        TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time) as total_request_time,
        (TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time) * provider_services.price) / 10000 as price_before_tax,
        provider_services.price / TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time) as price_with_tax
      FROM
        requests
      LEFT JOIN
        providers ON providers.id = requests.confirmed_provider
      LEFT JOIN
        provider_ratings ON requests.confirmed_provider = provider_ratings.provider_id
      LEFT JOIN
        provider_services ON providers.id = provider_services.provider_id AND provider_services.service_type_id = requests.request_type
      LEFT JOIN
        service_types ON requests.request_type = service_types.id
      WHERE
        (requests.user_id = $request->id AND requests.provider_status != 1 AND requests.status != 2 AND requests.status != 6 AND requests.user_accepted = 1 AND requests.provider_accepted = 1) OR
        (requests.user_id = $request->id AND requests.provider_status != 0 AND requests.status != 0 AND requests.status != 6 AND requests.user_accepted = 1 AND requests.provider_accepted = 1)
      GROUP BY
        requests.id";
```

The price is calculated at this point:

```
(TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time) * provider_services.price) / 10000 as price_before_tax,
```

This is working well only when the requests took full hours, for example:

**start_time : 2017-11-21 14:21:16**

**end_time: 2017-11-21 16:21:16**

In this case the price well calculated as you can see there:
[image]

But if I change the end_time to **2017-11-21 16:51:16**, the amount calculated is crazy as you can see there:

[image]

Comment: You expect for start-time 2017-11-21 14:21:16 and end_time to 2017-11-21 16:51:16... 2 hour and 30 minutes..   (2 * 30)  + (0.5 * 30) = 60 + 15 = 75 as price_before_tax?

Comment: Have you tried using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` using `SECOND`, divide that by `3600.0` to get the hours elapsed and then divide the service_price by those hours elapsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the issue:

```
$query = "SELECT
    requests.id as request_id,
    requests.request_type as request_type,
    service_types.name as service_type,
    requests.status,
    requests.provider_status,
    requests.amount,
    requests.s_latitude as latitude,
    requests.s_longitude as longitude,
    requests.confirmed_provider as provider_id,
    requests.user_accepted,
    requests.provider_accepted,
    providers.id as provider_id,
    providers.first_name as provider_first_name,
    providers.last_name as provider_last_name,
    providers.picture as provider_picture,
    AVG(provider_ratings.rating) as rating,
    provider_services.price as price_per_hour,
    requests.start_time,
    requests.end_time,
    TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time) as total_request_time,
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time))/60 as total_request_time_in_minutes,
    TIMEDIFF(now(),requests.start_time) as time_elapsed_since_start,
    (TIME_TO_SEC(now()) - TIME_TO_SEC(requests.start_time))/60 as time_elapsed_since_start_in_minutes,
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(),requests.start_time))/60 as time_elapsed_since_start_in_minutes,
    IF((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time))/60) > 15 ,(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time))/60) * (provider_services.price/60),15 * (provider_services.price/60)) as total_price,
    IF((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time))/60) > 15 ,(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(requests.end_time,requests.start_time))/60),15) as total_time
  FROM
    requests
  LEFT JOIN
    providers ON providers.id = requests.confirmed_provider
  LEFT JOIN
    provider_ratings ON requests.confirmed_provider = provider_ratings.provider_id
  LEFT JOIN
    provider_services ON providers.id = provider_services.provider_id AND provider_services.service_type_id = requests.request_type
  LEFT JOIN
    service_types ON requests.request_type = service_types.id
  WHERE
    (requests.user_id = $request->id AND requests.provider_status != 1 AND requests.status != 2 AND requests.status != 6 AND requests.user_accepted = 1 AND requests.provider_accepted = 1) OR
    (requests.user_id = $request->id AND requests.provider_status != 0 AND requests.status != 0 AND requests.status != 6 AND requests.user_accepted = 1 AND requests.provider_accepted = 1)
  GROUP BY
    requests.id";


$requests = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is much safer when you base the calculation on minutes. 
Like so.

**Query start_time : 2017-11-21 14:21:16 end_time: 2017-11-21 16:21:16**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2017-11-21 14:21:16', '2017-11-21 16:21:16') * (30 / 60)
```

**Result**

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2017-11-21 14:21:16', '2017-11-21 16:21:16') * (30 / 60)  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
60.0000
```

**Query start_time : 2017-11-21 14:21:16 end_time: 2017-11-21 16:51:16**

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2017-11-21 14:21:16', '2017-11-21 16:51:16') * (30 / 60)
```

**Result**

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2017-11-21 14:21:16', '2017-11-21 16:51:16') * (30 / 60)  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
75.0000
```